# How can I change the color of all my forms from just one of my forms?

Tags: c#, forms, colors, customization

I have tried:

```
//this code is triggered when i click a button on the form(lets call it form3)
// the first line works, but the second line is ReadOnly
this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Crimson;
DefaultBackColor = this.BackColor;
```

On form1, i have a button with the following code, without comments, triggered when i click it:

```
//this button is basically a refresh button for the background
this.BackColor = form3.DefaultBackColor;
```

I'm new to stackoverflow so help would be greatly appreciated, especially if an alternate code could be provided. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be of use?: `Application.OpenForms`

You could iterate through the collection and set the form colour that way.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class that gets and sets the color of a form.

When the user changes the color the global variable will change to (depending on how it's handled) probably the hexadecimal color value. Whenever another form is called just get the value that was set.